# Let $s(n,k)$ denote the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. Prove that...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, stirling-numbers

Let $s(n,k)$ denote the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. Prove that
$$s(n, n-1) = {n\choose2} $$

-I am new to Stirling numbers, and looked up some definitions regarding it. I know that they count the number of permutations of n elements with k disjoint cycles.  Although I am unsure of how to prove this and what kind of proof method to use.

Comment: What does a permutation of $n$ things look like if it has $n-1$ disjoint cycles?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm really not sure.

Comment: Why not try n=3 first. Which permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ have 2 disjoint cycles? For example, (1,2)(3) has 2 disjoint cycles but (1,2,3) only one. Then try n=4...

Comment: so for $\{1,2,3\}$ there is (1,2)(3) (1,3)(2) and (2,3)(1)?

Comment: Yes! What about n=4 and three disjoint cycles?